# str split function doesn't work

Tags: c, string

I have this function that converts an unidimensional array into a bidimensional array. When I convert it, I need to keep a `\n` (newline) between every 4x4 square.

```
int     count_words(const char *str, char c)
{
    int     i;
    int     count;

    i = 0;
    count = 0;
    while (str[i])
    {
        while (str[i] && str[i] == c)
            i++;
        if (str[i])
        {
            count++;
            while (str[i] && str[i] != c)
                i++;
        }
    }
    return (count);
}

char    *get_word(const char *str, char c)
{
    char    *word;
    int     i;

    i = 0;
    word = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 500);
    while (str[i] && str[i] != c)
    {
        word[i] = str[i];
        i++;
    }
    word[i] = '\0';
    return (word);
}

char    **ft_strsplit(const char *s, char c)
{
    char    **split;
    int     words;
    int     i;

    i = 0;
    words = count_words(s, c);
    split = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * words + 1);
    if (split == NULL)
        return (NULL);
    while (*s)
    {
        if (*s == c)
            s++;
        if (*s)
        {

            if (*s == c)
            {
                split[i] = ft_strdup("\0");
                s++;
                //printf("=========>%s\n", split[i]);
                i++;
            }
            else{
                split[i] = get_word(s, c);
                s = s + ft_strlen(split[i]);

        //printf("%s\n", split[i]);
            i++;}
        }
    }
    split[i] = NULL;
    int  k = 0;
    while (split[k])
    {
        printf("%s\n", split[k]);
        k++;
    }
    return (split);
}
```

This is the input file:
[image]

This is converted in this unidimensional string (`const char *s`):

`#...\n#...\n#...\n#...\n\n.#..\n.#..\n.#..\n.#..\n\n###.\n..#.\n....\n....\n\n....\n....\n....\n####\n`

And this is the ouput, with random unpritable characters in it.

```
#...
#...
#...
#...

.#..
.#..
.#..
.#..
�P@��
###.
..#.
....
....

....
....
....
####
```

Why do that random characters appear there?

Comment: SO isn't a debugging service. Compile with symbols, run the code inside a debugger to trace through the program(s) line by line inspecting the values of the relevant variables to learn what is really going on. If then a *specific* question arises feel free to come back here.

Comment: Oh my word, this is a debugging service. Debugging is finding a logic error. That's what we do when an OP offers a repeatable example and a thorough description of the program.

Comment: How are you calling `ft_strsplit`? The break character should be `\n`.

Comment: `count_words` doesn't count separator. But you use to separator as `split[i] = ft_strdup("\0");`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if I run your code (using `\n` as break character), it runs fine.

Awful lot of memory for words (no harm though). You could do:

```
    i = 0;
    while (str[i] && str[i] != c) i++;

    word = malloc(i + 1);
    for (int j=0; j<i; j++) word[j]= str[j];
    word[j] = '\0';
```